# Transaction has been unconfirmed for two days

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, exchanges, bitcoin-atm

I have bought Bitcoin from a BitcoinATM in Romania and my transaction has not been confirmed yet. I e-mailed them and they told me "the network is busy but your transaction will be confirmed at some time". I have a couple of questions here:

1. They gave me a `coin.cz` URL of the transaction (https://coin.cz/address/35FC55vyEZr29jYPZKpVTYpiEThCaNqDYs) and it appears as unconfirmed, but if I search it on `blockchain.info` it does not appear at all. What is `coin.cz` and why does my transaction not appear on Blockchain.info?
2. Are there any chances that my money will be lost? What can I do to make sure they will give me my money?

Comment: @pebwindkraft not really a duplicate because I am adding up to the question there. I am also having a different context, because my transaction comes from a Bitcoin Exchange, not from a friend or something, so if you can help me, please do!

Comment: I cannot add on the reputation of coin.cz... I cannot say, if funds will be lost, maybe someone else in the audience has experience with coin.cz. Looking at their webpage, the tx  indicates a good amount of fees. Furthermore, there is "https://bitcoinfees.earn.com", showing how long a tx takes in average.

Comment: You transaction is confirmed now. coin.cz is likely one of the closest node that picked up your transaction made from BitcoinATM in Romania. However, because of the heavily congested network, it took a while before your transaction was propagated to other nodes.

Comment: It is not confirmed.